# Полная высота col в row Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap4

Как сделать так что бы вторая `col-12` была во всю высоту блока `row`? То бишь автоматически занимал всю оставшуюся высоту не зависимо какой высоты первый `col-12`.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.min-100 {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid min-100 d-flex flex-column">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark flex-shrink-0">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <!--<img src="../img/logo.png"/>-->
                    LOGO
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/page/pipelines.html">Pipelines</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

 <div class="row flex-fill align-content-start">
<div class="col-12">
content
</div>
<div class="col-12">
content
</div>
</div>
</div>
```